# Javascript - How to select an image loaded from an array

Tags: javascript, css

So, I have four images that I put on the page from an array using a loop. Now I have the four images on the page, but I am looking for a way to allow the user to click on any of the images and display a large version of whichever one they click. I was thinking of using a new empty array, using push? to store the clicked image, but I don't know how to click on the images (because I 'm not using an img tag) and load the one that is clicked.

[image]

```
var arrayarray= [
  "1.jpg",
  "2.jpg",
  "3.jpg",
  "4.jpg"
]; 
var clicked =[];
function asdasd (){
   for (var i = 0, j = arrayarray.length; i < j; i++) {
     var fmg = document.createElement('img');
       fmg.setAttribute("src", arrayarray[i]);
       fmg.setAttribute("class", "fmss");
       container.appendChild(fwfw);
       if (??){
         clicked.push(i);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to define "select". there are many ways to do what you want, but there are only few correct ones (in terms of performance/SEO...)

Comment: I meant "clicked image"

Comment: @vsync even the least efficent would be fine. I am new with javascript

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't know how to click on the image" ? I don't think that I got your usecase. You have an array full of images, from which you generate items (images) to display on your page. Now you want to trigger a click-event on a specific image to load and display it in full size. is that correct? Do you want to do switch images every x seconds or should it be static? Sounds like a usual "imageslider" to me.

Comment: Are you asking how to allow the *user* to click on any of the images and display a large version of whichever one they click? *"because I 'm not using an img tag"* - You are creating img elements with your JS though. Those elements can receive click events.

Comment: SO you want the clicked image to be displayed bigger or something?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes exactly, a large version of whichever one they click.

Comment: So you need to add an EventHandler to your "fmg" obj inside your loop. e.g.
fmg.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Item: " + this.href + " was clicked")
});

Comment: You will need something like this, or it will never work.
container.appendChild(fwfw); fwfw.addEventListener('click', yourFunction);
And yourFunction simply takes that image and scales it to fullscreen/bigger and centers on the document. Another click revrses this. But the eventListener is very important here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `onClick` event to an image node.

Selecting the image logic is handled by `onClick` function. In my example `selectedImage` variable stores the selected url.

**See working example:**

```js
const images = [
  "1.jpg",
  "2.jpg",
  "3.jpg",
  "4.jpg",
]; 

let selectedImage = null;

const result = document.getElementById('result');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

const onClick = function() {
  selectedImage = this['data-url']; // or this.src
  
  // just for showing output in html
  result.innerText = selectedImage;
};

// on Init
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  const fmg = document.createElement('img');
  fmg.setAttribute("src", images[i]);
  fmg.setAttribute("class", "fmss");
  fmg.setAttribute("alt", images[i]);
  fmg.onclick = onClick;
  fmg['data-url'] = images[i];
  container.appendChild(fmg);
}
```

```css
.fmss { border: 2px solid black; margin: 10px; }
.result { margin: 20px; }
```

```html
Click me
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Upvote from me for this good example. One short remark: why are you using "var" in the for-loop when you used "let" on other places (I know the difference of var and let, just can't see a reason for using var in this - to have it consistent I guess let would be "better" - I know it's micrological.)

Comment: @asattler I just copied over the code :) Let me fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

No array needed. Just set the `src` of the big picture the to `src` of the clicked picture.

```js
let main = document.getElementById("main");  // Get reference to main image

// Set up click event handler on thumbnail container
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Check to see if the clicked element is a thumbnail
  if(event.target.classList.contains("thumb")){
    main.src = event.target.src;  // Set main picture to match the thumbnail
  }
});
```

```css
.thumb { width:40px; }
#main { width:125px; }
```

```html
<div id="picContainer">
  <img src="https://spectator.imgix.net/content/uploads/2015/06/Emoji.jpg?auto=compress,enhance,format&crop=faces,entropy,edges&fit=crop&w=620&h=413" class="thumb">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/43/7b/9b/437b9bbf3fde6d6a331b52bf6c422850.jpg" class="thumb">
  <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/ghfyz.wgnwv/v/vspfiles/photos/LOF-A3-3650-2.gif" class="thumb">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQisqxRpIXDaOgpdYoy_4UgSKLjaFXM6qIEa4zAOjFIsh_Plp5R" class="thumb">
</div>
<img id="main" src="">
```